# Apply Text classification on Social Media Comments

Tags: nlp

I need to perform Classification on Instagram comments.
I searched a lot but I am getting options for Sentiment Analysis.

Since the comments are not very long text, summarization also doesnt look like an option.

I want the classification to be like the below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are dealing with a **multi-class text classification problem**. You need to train a custom AI model to serve your specific purpose. Either you can go by creating a model from scratch, example using LSTMs or you can use some pre-trained models and train them on your custom dataset.

This [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-deep-learning-using-bert-b59ca2f5c613https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-deep-learning-using-bert-b59ca2f5c613) could be a good starting point. It uses BERT as the base model. Note- this is a pre-trained model, and you can look for similar models at [HuggingFace](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tasks/sequence_classification).

You may also want to check [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-model-comparison-and-selection-5eb066197568) out. It contains some basic models which may be a good try for your task.